# Could not initialize class org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory

Tags: java, maven, jetty

I git  clone a maven project from github(https://github.com/babylikebird/common-admin).  And i add a jetty plugin on pom.   It's ok to  clean,complier and  install ,but it can 't run with jetty.
here is jetty plugin on pom

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.3.7.v20160115</version>
</plugin>
```

bug message

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.3.7.v20160115:run (default-cli) on project common-admin: 
    Execution default-cli of goal org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.3.7.v20160115:run failed: 
    A required class was missing while executing org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.3.7.v20160115:run: 
    Could not initialize class org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory
```

Please help.